# Remove Duplicate Rows from SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

I have prepared a SSRS report which displays as

```
 Country    Sector
 -------    -------
 UK         banking 
 US         Banking
 US         Banking  
 Ireland    Sports   
 Ireland    Sports
```

My Data Set has CompanyName,Country and Sector.I want to group various distinct sector names under country.But I am getting duplicate results as shown above because the company names are different for all rows.I want to remove this duplicacy as I want to display only Country and Sector.Kindly advisse how to do this whithout using distinct in query.

Comment: please add the company name to the data. it'll be easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

Just group dataset by Sector and Country.

Assuming this query as example:

```
select 'a' as company, 'UK' as Country, 'banking' as Sector
union all
select 'b' as company, 'US' as Country, 'banking' as Sector
union all
select 'c' as company, 'Ireland' as Country, 'Sports' as Sector
union all
select 'd' as company, 'Ireland' as Country, 'Sports' as Sector
```

You'll get this dataset (not sure if it is similar to yours)

[image]

**EDIT: Setting Sector under Country**

Configure the row grouping as follows
[image]

And you will get the this preview:

[image]

Let me know if it meets your requeriments.

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/2647648/alejandro-zuleta.Your suggestion worked.This the exact solution I needed.